# download file in telegram.bot api using mvc c#

Tags: telegram-bot

I am using this code to download file from my bot.
this work in local but does'nt work in server.
i'm using webhook. please help me.
thanks

```
private async Task SaveFileAsync(Update update, TelegramBotClient bot)
    {
        string fs = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+ @"Uploads\";
        var FileId = update.Message.Document.FileId;
        var fileInfo = await bot.GetFileAsync(FileId);
        var filename = fileInfo.FileId + "." + fileInfo.FilePath.Split('.').Last();
        string strFilePath = fs + filename;
        FileStream saveImageStream = System.IO.File.Open(strFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        await bot.DownloadFileAsync(fileInfo.FilePath, saveImageStream, CancellationToken.None);
        saveImageStream.Dispose();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcdT9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

this method should be `void` and without `async`.
 and then we must remove `await` before `bot.DownloadFileAsync`